# 2 String with integer values Compare validation

Tags: validation, string-comparison

I've a checked list box. I need to ensure whether the checked items in the list box values are in the values of another string.

Another string values is string SubList={"234,254,235,546,273,124"};

I need to get the checkedlist items in a string and to compare the values whether it is present or not in SubList values.

All values in both strings are integers. I mean listbox values also integers just like SubList.

Please give me code.

Comment: What language are you using? Please format your question so the issue is more clear. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: C# checkedlistbox in windows forms

Comment: As I understand it you have an array of strings like `arr = {"123", "456", "789"}` and you have a few checkboxes and you're trying to find the text of the checkbox (ie one checkbox has the text 'abc' and another has the text '123') and you want to determine if the value in the checkbox the user checked is one of the strings in your array. So if the user checks the item 'abc' then you get false and if the user checks '123' you get true. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Nope...There is a checked list box with values 223,442,556 and these are checked items. I need to check whether each of these number are present in string SubList={"223,442,646"}; Since 556 is not present in SubList it should say that 556 is not authorized.

Comment: string[] str = MasterForm.SubList.Split(',');
                    String[] itemArr = new String[chklstSubList.CheckedItems.Count];
                    Int32 counter = 0;
                    if (chklstSubList.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (object o in chklstSubList.CheckedItems)
                        {
                            String temp = Convert.ToString(o);
                            itemArr[counter] = temp;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] a = new int[]{2, 5, 7};
    int[] b = new int[] { 2, 6, 7, 8};
    var nonintersect = a.Except(b);
    foreach(int value in nonintersect)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

prints 5